# Can't connect to an external MySQL server using PhpStorm

Tags: mysql, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide, datagrip

I'm actually struggling to set up a connection to my external MySQL database in PhpStorm. I'm getting this error :

```
The specified database user/password combination is rejected: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJException: Access denied for user '****afr_****nia'@'************************************' (using password: YES)
```

My address, my database name, and my user/password combination are correct.

Here is a link of the logs while it's happening, there is clearly a driver or configuration problem but can't figure what is it...

[Log file](https://gofile.io/d/wxSmKw)

My SQL base doesn't have SSL and SSL is disabled on my side.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you able to connect with those credentials using something like MySQL Work Bench?

Comment: Yes I can connect

Comment: As far as I know you can select the jdbc driver PhpStorm ist using for a database connect.

Comment: Yes but which one should I select ?

Comment: @JulesRC go to driver's general tab and select the correct `Class` `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`. See [documentaion](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/configuring-database-connections.html#change-the-driver-version) for details.

Comment: @VasiliiChernov It's still not working... Have any solutions?

Comment: @JulesRC could you create an issue in our bugtracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE ?